# How to loop through TypeScript enum?

Tags: typescript

I have next enum:

```
export enum Suite {
  Spade = '♠',
  Heart = '♥',
  Club = '♣',
  Diamond = '♦',
}
```

Trying to implement loop, but getting error

```
  for (let suite in Suite) {
    console.log('item:', Suite[suite]);
  }
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof Suite'.   No index
> signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof
> Suite'.ts(7053)

[image: Screenshot]

How can I fix that?

Comment: Spelling suggestion: it's spelled "[suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_card_suit)"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to narrow the type of your `suite` key with a type constraint. You can do this by declaring it before the loop:

```js
enum Suite {
  Spade = '♠',
  Heart = '♥',
  Club = '♣',
  Diamond = '♦',
}

let suite: keyof typeof Suite;
for (suite in Suite) {
    const value = Suite[suite];
    // ...
}
```

Or use `Object.entries`:

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(Suite)) {
    // key = Spade, etc.
    // value = ♠, etc.
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAymCWAXYUDeBYAUFWAHAhgCYoC8UA5IAZk5ANFjgBLD4BOiUZ5gpmS31QDCAGzAAjDhUDGZL2xQAIvHwQA9iELjygMzJpAXyxZBwdgGtgATwBcUE6aUAzKIlO5gd2AmQBuLLaUsoACmsoeBA3JGAASjQ+HABjFQBndgA3fGFSMOQAbWsAXS8ZOMSlAwA6QSUAc0CzGihU9IisXUwsAHo2qABREER4FmAE+tYFXvNvXwD4kCSoHNrh9NyoVwB5EQArYFjEUtBEFnhB-zhwiKiMQqhphJLgcqqa0zqGsEjmvUwgA)

Answer (score 2):

I want to point out at Connor Low's answer that on the second approach the value is not the string but the actual enum type, so you could do:

```
for(const [,suite] of Object.entries(Suite)) {
    doSuiteFunction(suite)
}
```

where doSuitFunction is defined as:

```
function doSuiteFunction(suite:Suite)
```